# Получение контент с ссылками для другого блока

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как выбрать все ссылки из первого блока (кроме первого элемента), а потом вставить каждую из этих ссылок в новый блок. Приведу пример

```js
var allCategories = [];

allCategories.push($(".bl_nav__item").each(function(index) {
  $(this).eq(index).html();
}));


console.log(" allCategories =" + allCategories);

var btnShowCatrories = $(".js-btn_caterogy");

btnShowCatrories.one("click", function() {
  $(this).next(".bl_mainNav__category_full").html("<li class='bl_mainNav__category_item'>    </li>")
});
```

```css
.my_button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bl_mainNav__category_full {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bl_mainNav__category_item {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bl_nav">
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link active" href="/">Не надо этого</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link1">Ссылка1</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link2">Ссылка2</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link3">Ссылка3</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link4">Ссылка4</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link5">Ссылка5</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link6">Ссылка6</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link7">Ссылка7</a></li>
</ul>


<button class="my_button js-btn_caterogy">Получить ссылки</button>
<ul class="bl_mainNav__category_full">
  <!-- Сюда я хочу получить ссылки в li -->


</ul>
```

Как по нажатию на кнопку забрать все ссылки с их атрибутами (кроме первой) и собрать их в списке bl_mainNav__category_full, каждую ссылку в свой li. Не могу понять почему у меня в массив собирается какой-то мусор ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой из вариантов Вам нужен?
**Вариант 1** - https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/jKgGKV

```js
$(".my_button").one('click',function(){
  $(".bl_nav__link").each(function(i){
    if(i!=0)
      $(".bl_mainNav__category_full").append($(this))
  })
});
```

```css
.my_button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bl_mainNav__category_full {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bl_mainNav__category_item {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bl_nav">
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link active" href="/">Не надо этого</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link1">Ссылка1</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link2">Ссылка2</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link3">Ссылка3</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link4">Ссылка4</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link5">Ссылка5</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link6">Ссылка6</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link7">Ссылка7</a></li>
</ul>
<button class="my_button js-btn_caterogy">Получить ссылки</button>
<ul class="bl_mainNav__category_full">
  <!-- Сюда я хочу получить ссылки в li-->
</ul>
```

**Вариант 2** - https://codepen.io/qwerty_wasd/pen/zagEXa

```js
$('.my_button').one('click',function(){
  $('.bl_nav__link').each(function(i){
    if(i!=0) $(this).clone().appendTo('.bl_mainNav__category_full')
  })
});
```

```css
.my_button {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bl_mainNav__category_full {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.bl_mainNav__category_item {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="bl_nav">
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link active" href="/">Не надо этого</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link1">Ссылка1</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link2">Ссылка2</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link3">Ссылка3</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link4">Ссылка4</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link5">Ссылка5</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link6">Ссылка6</a></li>
  <li class="bl_nav__item"><a class="bl_nav__link" href="/link7">Ссылка7</a></li>
</ul>
<button class="my_button js-btn_caterogy">Получить ссылки</button>
<ul class="bl_mainNav__category_full">
  <!-- Сюда я хочу получить ссылки в li-->
</ul>
```